# TensorFlow not updating weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I'm trying to create a VERY simple neural network with no hidden layers, just input (3 elements) and linear output (2 elements).

I then define some variables to store configurations and weights

```
# some configs
input_size = 3
action_size = 2
min_delta, max_delta = -1, 1
learning_rate_op = 0.5
w = {}     # weights
```

I then create the training network

```
# training network
with tf.variable_scope('prediction'):
    state_tensor = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, input_size], name='state_tensor')
    w['q_w'] = tf.get_variable('Matrix', [state_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[1], action_size], tf.float32, tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
    w['q_b'] = tf.get_variable('bias', [action_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
    q = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(state_tensor, w['q_w']), w['q_b'])
```

I define the optimizer to minimize the square different between the target value and the training network

```
# weight optimizer
with tf.variable_scope('optimizer'):
    # tensor to hold target value
    # eg, target_q_tensor=[10;11]
    target_q_tensor = tf.placeholder('float32', [None], name='target_q_tensor')

    # tensors for action_tensor, for action_tensor matrix and for value deltas
    # eg, action_tensor=[0;1], action_one_hot=[[1,0];[0,1]], q_acted=[Q_0,Q_1]
    action_tensor = tf.placeholder('int64', [None], name='action_tensor')
    action_one_hot = tf.one_hot(action_tensor, action_size, 1.0, 0.0, name='action_one_hot')
    q_acted = tf.reduce_sum(q * action_one_hot, reduction_indices=1, name='q_acted')

    # delta
    delta = target_q_tensor - q_acted
    clipped_delta = tf.clip_by_value(delta, min_delta, max_delta, name='clipped_delta')

    # error function
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(clipped_delta), name='loss')

    # optimizer
    # optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate_op).minimize(loss)
    optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate_op).minimize(loss)
```

And finally, I run some values in an infinite loop. However, the weights are never updated, they maintain the random values with which they were initialized

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    s_t = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
    action = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
    target_q = np.array([10, -11, -12, 13])

    while True:
        if counter % 10000 == 0:
            q_values = q.eval({state_tensor: s_t})
            for i in range(len(s_t)):
                print("q", q_values[i])
            print("w", sess.run(w['q_w']), '\nb', sess.run(w['q_b']))

        sess.run(optim, {target_q_tensor: target_q, action_tensor: action, state_tensor: s_t})
```

I took the code from a working [DQN](https://deepmind.com/research/dqn/) implementation, so I figure I'm doing something blatantly wrong. The network should converge to:

```
          #   0 | 1         
####################
 1,0,0    #  10  13
 1,0,1    #   x -11
 1,1,0    # -12   x
```

But they do *not* change at all. Any pointers?

---

Turns out that clipping the loss is causing the issue. However, I don't understand why...

Comment: So the only way that gradient descent won't change the weights is if the loss is zero. Perhaps just try checking all the values in the computation graph in one run? Somewhere along the line something should become zero, if your loss is zero.

Comment: My loss is always 1 :|

Comment: Sorry, I meant the **gradient** of the loss, not the loss... Either way, try my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loss is always 1, then it means your `clipped delta` is always clipping it to 1. It strikes me as an odd choice to clip the loss anyways. Perhaps you meant to [clip the gradient of the loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127)? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462962/loss-clipping-in-tensor-flow-on-deepminds-dqn) also.

Removing the clipping entirely will (probably) work as well in simple cases.

Comment: Removing the clipping works for this example. But it is standard practice in DQN, both reward and td-error clipping. If you clip the loss, the gradients will also be small. However, what is the problem of clipping the loss itself? Why do the weights stop being updated?

Comment: How do you calculate the gradient of the clipped loss? It makes more sense to clip the rewards before calculating the loss.

Comment: I just let the optimizer calculate the gradients and update the weights. The problem with reward clipping is that you lose scale among different rewards, and its not suitable my problem

Comment: As in, what is the gradient of `f(x) = min(max(x, -1), 1) = clip(x, -1, 1)`? For `x > 1` or `x < 1` your gradient (derivative) goes to 0. If you can't calculate the gradients by hand, neither can the optimizer.

Consider instead the [sigmoid](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP_Kj9rL_QAhVI0GMKHWQ6AcYQFggjMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSigmoid_function&usg=AFQjCNEpIEO5M-lU2zKwJ8jbrMS-n4eI-w&bvm=bv.139782543,d.cGc) function.

Comment: I followed your second link. I won't clip the rewards, just set them as linear outside the `[-1, 1]` interval